# Spanning set of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V is a vector space with a dimension rather than 0. 
May a subspace of V rather than itself have a spanning set?

For example, let our set Z only consists of the zero vector. So, it is a subspace of V.
Can I find a spanning set for Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The space $\{0\}$ is spanned by the empty set. And it is also spanned by $\{0\}$. Actually, every vector space is spanned by itself.

Comment: If a set T consists of vectors other than 0, can it also be spanning set of {0}? Since when we multiply ever vector in a vector space by scalar 0 it will be 0 vector.

Comment: No. The set $\{0\}$ spans only the space $\{0\}$.

Comment: In Bernard Kolman's book there is such a definition"Let S be a set of vectors in a vector space V. If every vector in V is a linear combination of the vectors in S, then the set S is said to span V, or V is spanned by the set S.

Comment: I believe you. And… ?

Comment: According to this definition, Let A={0}. Every vector in A can be written as linear combinations of the vectors in the set T which I mentioned in the up comment. Therefore, I had thought that T is spanning set of A.

Comment: Is use [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Definition): the  span of a set $S$ of vectors is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $S$. It is equivalent ot the definition that you mentioned *unless* $S=\emptyset$.

Comment: Can you simply explain to me where I'm making a mistake. I'm also still trying to understant the definition that you gave me.

Comment: Which mistake did you make?

Comment: With my thinking way as I talked in the up comment. A basis of a vector space is a spanning set of every subspace of that vector space.

Comment: Yes, that **is** a mistake. A spanning set $S$ of a vector space $V$ must *always* be a subset of $V$. But the only subspace of $V$ which contains a basis of $V$ is $V$ itself. So, $V$ is the only subspace of $V$ spanned by a basis of $V$.

Comment: But according to the Bernard Kolman's definition my reasoning must be true. However, probably I don't understand the definition exactly because of my English. Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: **No!** Bernhard Kolman says that $S$ is a **subset** of $V$, just like I said.

Comment: I wrote my reasoning . https://pasteboard.co/Ic6TPFr.jpg

Comment: You are repeating yourself and you are **not** reading what  Bernard Kolman wrote. In order that a set $S$ spans a vector space $V$, $S$ must be a **subset** of $V$. Your set $S$ is **not** a subset of $\{[0,0]\}$.